# my website says "memory_limit = 256M" how do i remove it?

Tags: wordpress, themes

So when I go on this website I keep getting `memory_limit = 256M` on the left had corner. My website is on wordpress, hosted on godaddy.com

I literally have no idea how to removie this. I've tried everything, even increasing the memory on website. I was on the phone with a tech from godaddy for one hour and he couldn't figure it out either.

Someone please help!

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3InDP.png)

Comment: If you're hitting the memory limit, it means something is wrong with a script.

Comment: That's a PHP setting, defined in the php.ini file

Comment: Can you please post the website url link, so only we can figure out the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your wp-config.php file:

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
```

Add number what ever you want in place of 256.
check out the Link https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Increasing_memory_allocated_to_PHP